QGIS 3.36.1 `Temporal Controller` not working with WMTS?
I am using QGIS version 3.36.1-Maidenhead.
I am trying to reproduce the screencast posted on github. But I am not able to reproduce the date switching in Temporal Controller.
Before creating an Issue on github I want to make sure that this is indeed a bug and not my local problem.
I would like you to confirm the date switching problem and specify your version of QGIS as an answer to this question.
Layer name:
Air Temperature (Monthly, Near Surface, Noah LSM, Best Available, GLDAS)
WMTS service:
https://gibs-a.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/wmts.cgi
